# Need to Count Cells with values greater zero that are not in a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am making a spreadsheet for a multi-month event.

[image: See Spreadsheet here]

I need to count the number of individual events each competitor came to.
(Counting the 'Overall' Column to show how many shows in the last yellow column).
Any column that shows "0" means that the competitor did not compete in that month's event.

[image]

Comment: I have...but I need the ones that have "0" to not be added in because they did not compete...the 0 is a place holder essentially

Comment: But if you add 0, it won't do anything to the total :S May be I've not understood. I also don't understand how the overall works... 19 + 2 (in Feb) is 21 and 45+42 is 87 (in Total)

Comment: Oh! Sorry I misunderstood you question...for total shows I need each overall column with a total larger than zero to count as '1' so for the second row in the picture February would count as 1 and March and April would not count so the total should read '1' in the "total shows" column

Comment: Can you please edit your question and provide 2 images. The way your spreadsheet is now, and another one the way you'd like it to look

Comment: Just edited and added it in

Comment: So is your question about the `Total Shows` or the `Overall` ?

Comment: Total shows...I'm using the Overall columns in order to count the number of shows each competitor came to

Comment: You could use `SumIf`The logic is to count the overall columns but instead of using the value, use 1 or 0. EG in AE 3 (assuming that is the first row of TotalShows, use `=(IF (O3>0,1,0) +IF (S3>0,1,0)+IF (AA3>0,1,0)+IF (AD3>0,1,0))`

Comment: I'm struggling with the fact that they are not a range but individual cells

Comment: Oh I apologize the entire comment hadn't loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do this manually, using an if statement to ascertain if there is a valid or not

So, in the Total Shows column, in the first row (with a yellow background) you'd have something like (I've assumed the first row with a yellow background is row 3)

```
=(IF (O3> 0, 1, 0) +IF (S3 > 0, 1 , 0) +IF (AA3 > 0, 1, 0) + IF(AD3 > 0, 1, 0))
```

You can then copy this down the Total Shows column